# Typescript member method passed into KO click binding ends up with "wrong" scope

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I'm writing a single page application using KnockoutJS and Typescript.

The issue is this, I have a MainViewModel with the method:

```
public addToCase(email) {
    this.addToCaseVM.setEmail(email, this.getEmailBody());
};
```

I have an email view in my page that has an "Add To Case" button that is bound in html like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click: $root.addToCase" data-toggle="modal" href="#addToCaseModal"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp;Add To Existing Case</a>
```

Where $root is my MainViewModel. When this button is clicked the 'email' parameter of the function is the correct selected email in the MainViewModel but the scope of the function is also the EmailViewModel, not the MainViewModel on which the function is defined.

I understand why this happens, I'm interested in how to solve the particular issue in Typescript since I can't declare a pointer to the MainViewModel instance like I would in pure javascript:

```
var MainViewModel = (function(){ 
    var self = this; 

    this.addToCase = function(email) {
        self.addToCaseVM.setEmail(email, self.getEmailBody());
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function literal so that you can pass the parent object to your addToCase function, but that seems like working around the problem rather than solving it.

```
data-bind="click: function(data) {$root.addToCase(data,$root)}"
```

Comment: This is a workaround, but after some testing it seems right to me. After you wrap the member function call in an outer closure it allows the inner call to have the correct scope and explicitly states what you are trying to do. I'm going with this in my project. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

My solution to this was to declare class method and leave it empty untill constructor is called, then define method body. This way method will be scoped correctly.

```
class MainViewModel {

    addToCase: (email) => void;

    constructor() {
        this.addToCase = (email) => {
            this.addToCaseVM.setEmail(email, this.getEmailBody());
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

If your `MainViewModel` is a singleton then you can use that pattern to create a static reference.

```
class MainViewModel {

    static self:MainViewModel;

    constructor() {
        self = this;
    } 

    addToCase = function(email) {
        MainViewModel.self.addToCaseVM.setEmail(email, MainViewModel.self.getEmailBody());
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I was hoping for a cleaner implementation or one that would work in other cases where MainViewModel was any generic parent viewmodel and not a singleton.

Comment: Agreed, the singleton is a bit artificial - and @MattBurland's answer is the better one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `() =>` to preserve lexical scoping.

I have made this into a fully working example for demonstration purposes, but you can see that it is just the `() =>` that does the magic.

```
function setEmail(email: string, callback: Function) {
    callback();
}

class MainViewModel { 
    addToCase(email: string) {
        setEmail(email, () => {this.getEmailBody();});
    }

    getEmailBody() {
        alert('getEmailBody');
    }
}

var model = new MainViewModel();
model.addToCase('hello');
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work in my case because the addToCase member of the MainViewModel class is being handed off to Knockout as a function closure which is then invoked by jQuery with a different scope. The problem is that the _this variable that the typescript compiler generates for you in your example gets generated in the wrong scope to begin with in my application.